# Creating a File in Android using C++ or SDL

Tags: android, c++, sdl

I'm making a game using C++ and SDL that is built for android, I'm trying to make something like saving the progress of the game or the completed levels, so I want to create a file to save the data in it, how do I create a file in and access on android, or what is the path for internal android studio and if I can create a folder containing that file as well ?

Answer (score 0):

The standard C++ iostream or C stdio functions should work just fine.  Just make sure your app has access to the directory you write to.

Comment: And how to get the path of the directory i'm writing to in android, like if i wanna write the file in the root without any subfolders, what should be the path of that, or how to get the access to the root directory

Comment: Root of the phone?  You can't-  you won't have write permission there (and you shouldn't anyway, its a Linux filesystem, files don't go in root).  Root of your app's private data directory?  Use ANativeActivity.internalDataPath

Comment: Currently i'm using SDL_GetPrefPath(), works fine on windows but not on android, and also if i'm using the standard C++ iostream what path should i provide that's my only problem here i can't seem to be able to access any directory to write to